# Close used cells and open unused cells in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collections, uicollectionviewcell

I try to **close** used cells and **open** unused cells in **collectionView**. I think it's need to make in `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool`

I have array of strings:

```
var arrayOfStrings: [String] = ["01:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00"]
```

And me need to **close** for choose cells which have strings from my `arrayOfStrings` in my collectionView and leave **open** cells for choose which is not present in my array.

How i can do it?

It's me code:

```
var allTimeArray: [String] = ["01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00"]
var arrayOfStrings: [String] = ["01:00", "05:00", "06:00", "07:00"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return allTimeArray.count

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as! BookTimeCell

    cell.timeLabel.text = allTimeArray[indexPath.item]

    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    // i think need use IF...
    return true

}
```

And my collectionView image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to search arrayOfStrings whether it contains the item to be displayed and return false to close selection

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

 let item = allTimeArray[indexPath.row]
    for er in arrayOfStrings
     if(er == item)
       return false

  return true

}
```

Or in short

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {


     return !(arrayOfStrings.contains(allTimeArray[indexPath.row]))


}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeCell", for: indexPath) as! BookTimeCell

    cell.timeLabel.text = allTimeArray[indexPath.item]

    if arrayOfStrings.contains(cell.timeLAbel.text) {
        //configure for choosed cell.
    } 
    else {
        //Configure for open cell.
    }

    return cell

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let selectedString = allTimeArray[indexPath.item]
    if !arrayOfStrings.contains(selectedString)
    {
        arrayOfStrings.append(selectedString)

        //Reload the cell at indexpath.
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
    }
}
```